# Partitioning large dataframes for an efficient left join?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, left-join

I have two large dataframes with the same structure, and roughly the same amount of data, and I'm left-joining them to determine if any of the rows are missing in one DF but not the other. The dataframes are large enough (up to 80 million rows, or ~40Gb) to make the broadcast join not an option. The number of missing rows is generally small, up to 10K for worst cases. The join is on an expression over 2-4 columns (same on both sides), in the form of `concat(coalesce(colA, ""), "|", coalesce(colB, ""), "|", coalesce(colC, ""))`, as some of the key columns can be NULL.

We're looking at using partitioning (either prior or after the join), as the shuffle caused by the join  seem to cause low performance in our production environment. What's the recommended way to partition the dataframes for an efficient left join?

Comment: Using multiple clauses for the join (rather than concatenating everything) and partitioning based on columns in that order may give you a good performance boost.

Comment: Also, have you considered using a Bloom filter or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all partitioning can improve performance of the `join` operation **only**, if the `join` operation will be performed **multiple times** without changing at least one DataFrame.

Similar answer is already provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604297/why-pre-partition-will-benefit-spark-job-because-of-reducing-shuffling) - using partitioning prior to one-time `join` will just cause shuffle in a different place.

Using partitioning after `join` will not have any positive effect.

Also partitioning effect on `join` operations topic is explained in [this](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do) book at the page 61.

Comment: Does the join type makes a difference? If I join two datasets with the exact same condition twice, but one is a left join, and the other one is a right join - would pre-partitioning give any performance improvement, or are these considered "different" joins?

Comment: Is it not about type of join. This is about values. Consider: `df.join(df2, "A")`. To perform this join spark will move rows with same value in A column to same node - this is shuffling. Pre-partitioning will do the same, but before join operation. For example if after this join above you will do something like: `df.join(df3, "A")` - i mean join by the same column - then you can consider pre-partitioning - because df will be shuffled only once. Otherwise if you have different set of columns for join - pre-partitioning will not help.